# how to get gulp-better-sass-inheritance to compile ALL files

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have 3 folders with SCSS files prefixed with _. I want to compile all files and save the output (if any).

For now, I have to create a file in the BASE folder that @imports the corresponding file from a specific folder:

**Element.Footer.scss**:

```
@import "Element\\Footer";
```

Files and folders:

> BASE
>
> -Element
>
> -- _Footer.scss
>
> -- _Table.scss
>
> -Layout
>
> -- _Other.scss
>
> -- Element.Footer.scss

Creating a file just to import another file seems a little "wrong".
Is there a better way to do this??

**gulpfile.js**:

```
'use strict';

const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel, fiber } = require("gulp");
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const changed = require("gulp-changed");
const cached = require('gulp-cached');
const sourceMaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");

const targets = {
    STYLE: "style",
    SCRIPT: "script"
};

const outputs = {
    NESTED: "nested",
    COMPRESSED: "compressed",
    COMPACT: "compact",
    EXPANDED: "expanded",
    CONCAT: "concat"
};

const changedTask = (target, sourceMap = false) => {
    const destPath = () => sourceMap ? "../" : "./_Build/" + target.toUpperCase() + (sourceMap ? "_MAPS/" : "/");

    const tasks = (output) => {
        const gIf = require('gulp-if');
        const filter = require('gulp-filter');
        const sourceMapCondition = () => {(output !== outputs.COMPRESSED && !sourceMap)};

        if (output !== outputs.CONCAT) {
            if (target === targets.STYLE) {
                const sass = require("gulp-sass");
                const sassInherit = require("gulp-better-sass-inheritance");

                return src("./STYLE/**/*.scss")
                    .pipe(changed(destPath(target)))
                        .pipe(gIf(global.isWatching, cached("sass")))
                    .pipe(sassInherit({base: "./STYLE/"}))
                        .pipe(filter(function (file) {
                            return !/\/_/.test(file.path) || !/^_/.test(file.relative);
                        }))
                        .pipe(gIf(sourceMapCondition, sourceMaps.init()))
                    .pipe(sass({ fiber: fiber, outputStyle: output }).on("error", sass.logError))
                        .pipe(gIf(sourceMapCondition, sourceMaps.mapSources((sourcePath, file) => {
                            return "../" + target.toUpperCase() + "/" + sourcePath;
                        })))
                    .pipe(rename((path) => {
                        var basename = path.basename;

                        if (path.dirname !== ".") {
                            if (basename.charAt(0) === "_") {
                                basename = basename.slice(1);
                            }

                            basename = path.dirname + "." + basename.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + basename.slice(1);
                        }

                        path.basename = basename;
                        path.dirname = "./";
                    }))
                    .pipe(dest(destPath(target)));
            }
            else if (target === targets.SCRIPT) {

            }
        }
        else {
            if (target === targets.STYLE) {

            }
            else if(target === targets.SCRIPT) {

            }
        }
    };

    return tasks(outputs.NESTED);
};

const watcher = () => {
    global.isWatching = true;
    watch("./STYLE/**/*.scss", changedStyle);
    watch("./SCRIPT/**/*.js");
};

const changedStyle = () => {
    return changedTask(targets.STYLE)
};

const changedScript = () => {
    return changedTask(targets.SCRIPT);
}

exports.default = watcher;
exports.changeStyle = changedStyle;
exports.changeScript = changedScript;
```